# 2010: Custom List Template ID

Tags: 2010, document-library, client-object-model, list-template

I searched everywhere, but could not find a solution that worked for me.

We've created a default document library, changed it a bit and saved it as a new document library template from the user interface. I can create document libraries based on this template successfully.

However, I have some CSOM code that creates a library automatically for me. It is now based on the template "101", which is the default document library. I want to create the library in code based on my custom document library.

I understood that I need a custom list template ID (which should be > 10000), but I cannot find out how I can find the custom list template id's. I found commands that list the default list template id's (i.e. 100, 101) but not the custom list template ID's. How can I find the custom list template ID's?

Answer (score 7):

### How to identify a SharePoint List Template ID (in Browser)

1. The global variable `g_wsaListTemplateId` is available on the client
       side when the List is rendered

   Navigate to List - Press `F12` to launch `Dev Tools` ([details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and switch to `Console` window and run:

   `console.log(g_wsaListTemplateId)`

   [image]
2. Export List Schema
   Construct the following query to export List Schema:

   ```
   https://fabifam.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={ListGuid}
   ```

   where {ListGuid} corresponds to the List Guid

   To find out `List Guid` go to `List` - `List Settings` and copy List Guid from URL as demonstrated below

   [image]

   In the generated List Schema find the attribute named `ServerTemplate` that corresponds to List Template ID

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand your answer. What is console.log? Which List Guid are you talking about?

Comment: Martijn, the answer has been updated, hope it's more clear now

Comment: Thanks. I tried both procedures. In both cases it returns 101, which is the id of the default document library and not the one with the content that I created.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Save the list template file (.stp) locally
2. Change the extension to .zip and extract it
3. Open manifest.xml and check TemplateID number
4. Try by use this TemplateID in your code to create a list in a site that contains your custom list template

Comment: In my case that is "7", I thougt it should be greater that 10000: <TemplateID>7</TemplateID> <Configuration>0</Configuration> <FeatureId>{00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101}</FeatureId> <TemplateType>101</TemplateType>

Comment: I saved one in my VM and I got 111000 for TemplateID. Try it with 7 in your code anyway.

Comment: I did. It still gives me "Invalid List Template ID". Code snippet:
ListCreationInformation lci = new ListCreationInformation(); 
lci.Title = name;
lci.TemplateType = libraryType;
Where libraryType was 101 and is now 7

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to select all custom document templates programmatically? Look at the code example below

```
 var templates = SPContext.Current.Web.ListTemplates.OfType<SPListTemplate>().Where(t => t.IsCustomTemplate).Select(t => t.DocumentTemplate);
```

[Here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/06/19/get-all-list-templates-with-javascript-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/) you can find how you can deal with it through client side object model

Comment: I am working client side, so I cannot use the SPContext class.

Comment: What about this link - http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/06/19/get-all-list-templates-with-javascript-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/. The same but from the client side...

Comment: Sorry. Tried that. Doesn't even give me an error message. :(